# How to add C++REST SDK as a submodule with CMake?

Tags: cmake, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to build a project with numerous dependencies such as Boost, OpenSSL, and C++ REST SDK. However, it is required that the source code is included in the project workspace and that the library is built from said source code.

The most consistently successful way I have found to achieve this is though the use of `git submodule add <URL>`, `add_subdirectory`, `target_link_libraries`, and some clever projects built for this purpose such as [boost-cmake](https://github.com/Orphis/boost-cmake) and [openssl-cmake](https://github.com/viaduck/openssl-cmake).

Take for example the following project structure:

```
prjct
| include/
| libs/
| | boost-cmake/
| | openssl-cmake/
| | cpprestsdk/
| src/
| tests/
| CMakeLists.txt
```

For which the top-level CMakeLists.txt would contain:

```
...
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/boost-cmake)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/openssl-cmake)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/cpprestsdk)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME_L}
    PUBLIC
        Boost::system
        Boost::thread
        Boost::log
        Boost::program_options
        Boost::chrono

        ssl  # OpenSSL::SSL
        crypto  # OpenSSL::Crypto

        cpprestsdk::cpprest
)
...
```

However, in the case of the cpprestsdk library, I recieve the following error upon running `cmake ..` from `build/`:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:55 (add_library):
  Target "prjct" links to target "cpprestsdk::cpprest" but the target
  was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for and IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

**How can I link and use the C++ REST SDK within these constraints?**

Comment: If you include with `add_subdirectory` this project: https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk, then it creates the target `cpprest` (without a prefix `cpprestsdk::`). Note, that `boost-cmake` project you describe is just a wrapper around [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FetchContent.html) functions calls, which downloads the Boost sources during configuration and performs `add_subdirectory` to its sources. So it is nearly the same as you do with `cpprestsdk`. As for `openssl-cmake`, it uses `ExternalProject_Add` for build `openssl` at build stage of your project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev solves my problem. Can you post that as an answer please?